# how to get value in var , selected from dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have an dropdown named expenses. which have several options .
all i want , when i select a option a pop up will dispaly which contain the value which is selected from the dropdown.

dropdown in controllers,

```
$data['expenses']= $this->Ledger_model->get_codewise_ledgers( )
```

In view,

```
            echo "<p class=\"expenses\">";
            echo "<td>". form_dropdown('expenses' ,$expenses);
            echo "</td>";
```

and ajax code

```
   $('.expenses').change(function() {
            var ledger_name =$("select.expenses option:selected").val();

            alert ("The name of ledger you selected is "+ledger_name+".");
```

it's not working..

it says: "The name of ledger you selected is undefined."

Comment: We might need a bit more information. Can we have the `form_dropdown` function ?

Comment: check if your dropdown has values in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

var ledger_name =$("select.expenses option:selected").text();

In spite of

var ledger_name =$("select.expenses option:selected").val();

It may work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using jQuery. In jQuery, accessing selected option is a bit simplier:

```
var ledger_name = $("select.expenses").val();
```

or, in your change handler, you can use `this` keyword:

```
var ledger_name = $(this).val();
```